# Como unificar todos os Form's?

Tags: php

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema básico de validação de lubrificação para motores da oficina do meu pai, mas cheguei a um problema que não estou conseguindo solucionar.

o código executa a seguinte função:

- Pega todos os motores através do `foreach` no banco de dados com a lubrificação "**NÃO OK**".
- Depois, lista os motores criando um checkbox para cada motor **NÃO OK**.

O problema é que ao LISTAR os motores, são criados form's para cada um do motores e eu gostaria de deixar tudo dentro de **UM ÚNICO FORM**, listando todos os motores com a lubrificação atrasada.

**Código:**

```
                    foreach ($lubrificado as $value)
                {
                  if($value['nome_trp'] == "T01")
                  {
                    if($value['lubrificado'] == "N")
                    {
                      //print_r($lubrificado);
                      echo '<p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> '.$value['rgmotor'].'.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value='.$value['rgmotor'].'>Lubrificado ?</label></form>';
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

Resultado:

```
       <div class="column">
          <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 19.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=19>Lubrificado ?</label></form><p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 20.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=20>Lubrificado ?</label></form><p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 21.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=21>Lubrificado ?</label></form><p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 24.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=24>Lubrificado ?</label></form><p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 25.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=25>Lubrificado ?</label></form><p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 26.</strong></big></p><form action"lubrificarmotor.php" method="POST"><label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=26>Lubrificado ?</label></form>            </div>
```

Consegui algo assim:

```
?>
                <form action="lubrificarmotores.php" method="POST">
                <?php
                foreach ($lubrificado as $value)
                {
                  if($value['nome_trp'] == "T01")
                  {
                    if($value['lubrificado'] == "N")
                    {
                      ?>
                        <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> <?php echo ($value['rgmotor']) ?></strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo($value['rgmotor'])?>">Lubrificado ?</label>
                    <?php
                    }
                  }
                }
                ?>
                <br>
                <input class="button is-danger is-default" type="submit" name="Salvar" value = "Enviar">
                </form>
                <?php
              }
            }
          ?>
```

Resultado:

```
                                  <form action="lubrificarmotores.php" method="POST">
                                            <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 19</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="19">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                                <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 20</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="20">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                                <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 21</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="21">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                                <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 24</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="24">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                                <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 25</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="25">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                                <p class="has-text-centered"> Redutor com RG:<strong><big> 26</strong></big></p>
                        <label class="has-text-right" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="26">Lubrificado ?</label>
                                        <br>
                <input class="button is-danger is-default" type="submit" name="Salvar" value = "Enviar">
                </form>
```

Posso deixar desta maneira ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao site Matheus! Eu te peço para que transcreva o conteúdo da imagem da sua pergunta (copie o código) e substitua.

Comment: Editado o post.

Comment: Se quer um form só, porque pôs um <form> </form> para cada linha do campo?

Comment: Ele gera um form para cada linha por causa do foreach.

Comment: Então. Você tem um laço de repetição que gera múltiplos formulários; você quer apenas um; qual é a primeira coisa que lhe vem a cabeça?

Comment: @MatheusLucas sim, eu vi que ele gera um para cada linha, minha pergunta é pq pos no foreach se quer um form só para todas as linhas.

Comment: @MatheusLucas olha lá, pensou um pouco e avançou no resultado, isso é bom sinal. Mas poderia ter posto no campo de soluções, já que funcionou, e não na pergunta. Sobre "poder deixar assim", depende. Era isso que queria?

Comment: bacco, realmente era deste modo de queria !. valeu por me fazer pensar um pouco kkk

Comment: @MatheusLucas eu sugeriria você removero código completo da sua solução da pergunta e por no campo de resposta, e marcar como correta, assim fica o par pergunta e resposta certinho..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

deixa a tag < form > fora da estrutura de repetição "for", e dentro do "for" deixe o que você quer exibir.